# How to stay on a particular page after add/delete of a row in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatables for visualizing server side data. By default jquery datatables shows 10 entries. If I add more than 10 entries, datatables shows page number(s) depending on how many entries I have added.

The problem is that on every add/remove, datatables redraws and points me to the first page. After googling how to stay on the current page after redraw, I discovered that if I use datatables api, I can preserve the page state something like:

```
var dataTables = $("#mytable").DataTable();
dataTables.remove(tableRow).draw(false);
```

Is there a way to preserve page state, other than in example stated above, when using datatables initialized with **dataTable()** method?

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'return false' beside calling the function that you made for deleting rows. That prevents submit of form.

So like this:

```html
<span onclick="deleteRowfunction();return false;"></span>
```